# How to access the request body in SpringBoot's AccessDecisionVoter?

Tags: spring-boot, permissions, spring-security-oauth2

So we have a Authorisation server with which we create OAuth2 access token. All sub-systems verify the access token and may check the request path for permissions, however, in one of the sub-systems we need to look into the request body and extract the 'id' to check if the user has proper permission to submit the request. The request message is in JSON format and this is a POST request with client-provided id.

The id in the request is a process id and some users may not have right permission to some processes therefore we need the id to verify.

So while in `AccessDecisionVoter`, we only can get request URI but I can't get `HttpServletRequest` to read the message. (Note: We have a Request wrapper that allows us to read request body multiple times)

I tried to auto-wire `HttpServletRequest`, no luck. There is an error that no thread has been bound to the request

I was also thinking about implementing `UserDetailService` but again no luck as this is not being invoked by Spring boot. Remember that we are using a custom `AuthorizationServerTokenServices` and that is in a common library.

How do I get Http servlet request or the request body in `AccessDecisionVoter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement an `AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation>` where you can get the request. Does this not work:

```
public class MyAccessDecisionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        int result = ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        fi.getRequest() // this is the request
        // decide the outcome and set result

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the question is, is this the right place to do so? In terms of good practice?